# SQL Count for Each Repeated Number in Column

Tags: sql

I have this

```
m_id    p_id
112      8
340      8
928     16
190     16
290     16
... etc
```

How do I get this?

```
p_id    count(p_id)
8          2
16         3
```

I'm confused because I also want to make sure that it is counting the p_id while keeping the m_id values distinct.

Help please and thank you :)

Comment: This is a very basic aggregation query using `count(distinct)`.

Answer (score 1):

Sample data

```
  CREATE TABLE #temp
                  (
             m_id INT, p_id INT
                  );

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
       (112, 8
       ),
       (340, 8
       ),
       (928, 16
       ),
       (190, 16
       ),
       (290, 16
       );
```

Query:

```
SELECT p_id, COUNT(*) [count(p_id)]
FROM #temp
GROUP BY p_id;
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this:

```
SELECT p_id, count(distinct m_id) from myTable group by p_id;
```

That's for if you want to count the number of distinct m_id's that are associated with each p_id, if you only want to count the number of p_id's in the table, drop the **distinct** keyword.